# Angular + Rails Access-Control Headers

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when doing an $http.post to the opencalais API from my Angular controller in my Rails app:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.thomsonreuters.com/permid/calais?access-token=APIKEY. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://developer.permid.org' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Here's the API call inside my Angular controller:

```
function fetchTags() {
  var token = API-KEY,
      query = $scope.brief.description;
  $http.post('https://api.thomsonreuters.com/permid/calais?access-token=' + token, query, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/raw',
      'OutputFormat': 'application/json',
      'X-AG-Access-Token': API-KEY,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
  }).success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

I've read and tried several different ways of setting the Access-Control headers, either through the Angular request or even through something like a before_filter in the Rails application_controller.rb, but they all seem to result in the same response.

Furthermore, I've replicated the request in Postman, just by setting the URL and Headers to the same as above, and it works perfectly.

Any ideas or links would be greatly appreciated, thanks

**EDIT**: Here's the request/response headers from Chrome:

Request:

> OPTIONS /permid/calais?access-token=API-KEY HTTP/1.1
>   Host: api.thomsonreuters.com
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
>   Origin: http://localhost:3000
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, access-control-allow-origin, content-type, outputformat, x-ag-access-token, x-csrf-token
>   Accept: */*
>   DNT: 1
>   Referer: http://localhost:3000/
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Response:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://developer.permid.org
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, x-ag-access-token, authorization, outputformat, content-type, x-openmatch-numberofmatchesperrecord, x-openmatch-datatype, x-calais-language
>   Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
>   Origin: http://localhost:3000
>   Content-Length: 0
>   Connection: keep-alive

Comment: Did you set anywhere a URL to `http://developer.permid.org`?

Comment: No, I believe that comes from the response headers.  I've updated the question with the request/response.

Comment: Looks like this API doesn't support CORS. So you cannot use it from Angular.